# cant load keras model

Tags: python, django, tensorflow

I'm trying to load my trained TensorFlow model in Django for some reason I'm not able to load it.
i could load it when i put the code in a seperate file but when i call the model.predict it throws an error "'function' object has no attribute 'predict'"

load.py file

```
import tensorflow as tf


def load_models():
    model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model(r"..models/plant.model")
    print(model)
    return model
```

this is my code in the view.py file
 def prepare(request):

```
from .load import loader
model = loader
if request.method=='POST':
    file_path_enc=request.FILES["file_path"]
new_file_path = file_path_enc
fs=FileSystemStorage()
name=fs.save(new_file_path.name,new_file_path)
url=fs.url(name)

DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
filepath=DIR+url

IMG_SIZE = 250 
img_array = cv2.imread(filepath) 
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))  
reshape=new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
print(reshape)
pred=model.predict([reshape])


return render (request,'file.html')
```

Comment: Can you add some error / exception that you might be facing?

Comment: i tired loading the mode in seperate py file and return it to the views.py there was no error but after words when i tried the mode.predict() there was a error "function' object has no attribute 'predict'"